# Asp.net expand button

Tags: asp.net, expand

I my asp.net website project with c# code, I have a table in which I generate rows programmatically. Some of those rows have expand buttons to display more information. For now, I catch the postback caused by the button, parse the name of the button that caused the postback and regenerate all my rows, adding a label to the appropriate rows with the informations that needed to be expanded.

I was wondering if there was a better way to implement a expand/collapse mechanisme that would not require me to regenerate all rows. I tried searching my tables for the rows to add the information, but since the rows are generated programmatically, the table is empty at each postback caused by the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a list variable that keeps the row instances that you generated for your table. At postback, instead of generating, you iterate your list and add them in the table. At the same time, you can check, for each row, if it's the row where you need to add your information.

Comment: I tried your method. It indeed takes less time to refresh the page than before.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do that expanding on the client, on button click fetch server for content or you can render all html needed for expanding but with hidden style and then on button click with javascript change style.

Approach 1 - Ajax call and replace content - http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx

Approach 2 - Easily done with jQuery :

```
<asp:Panel ID="showHidePanel" runat="server" style="display:none;">
  Additional content
</asp:Panel>
<input type="button" onclick="$('#<%=showHidePanel.ClientID %>').show(); return false;" value="Show" />
```

Comment: Your second approach sound simple enough. I will try it and compare with my current approach. Thank you.